# Vue.js DOM added after initialization don't interact

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an HTML page updated with ajax contents. 
I'm using Vue.js for some dynamic front-end events.

Dynamically added elements don't interact with the Vue.js instance, even if I try to forceUpdate.

How could I do that?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="click()">click will console something</button>
</div>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
      click: function() {
        console.log('clicked')
      },
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#app').append('<button v-on:click="click()">click here wont do anything</button>');

    app.$forceUpdate();
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how you add elements in Vue. Your contract with Vue is that it will control the DOM and you will provide it a model that describes how things should appear and work.

Let go of jQuery. If you want a button to conditionally appear, have a variable that controls its appearance, and set that variable to true.

If you really, really have to deal with DOM being added outside of Vue, then you will need to call `new Vue` on the newly added elements to put them under Vue's control.

Comment: I was trying to implement a very basic Vue system on top of a http://barbajs.org/ implementation. I don't want to use a Vue router on top of my current system. Is it possible to call a new Vue on an item append in a Vue element?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about using Barba and Vue together. I don't find any examples of people doing that, and I am not familiar with Barba, myself. It looks like it would take a bit of ingenuity, but should be possible.